# Bean required to defined as it autowired as service class implementation is available Depedency package

Tags: spring-boot

I Have Connection class and which basically uses RestExchange to pass and receive response, and this Connection is called in Reservation Class package by autowiring it.

However the autowiring requires the bean to be created in Reservation package while accessing it.

Any idea why it doesn't autowire directly from the dependency package, my problem is that it  requires Bean to be created for like other things RestTemplate which is used in Connection class dependency.

Even i have included the componentscan package in the application class.

ReservationConfig

```
    @Bean(name = "connection") {
            public Connection getConnection(){
                return new connection ();
    }
    
    
    
   @Bean(name = "restTemplate")
   public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
         return new RestTemplate();
   }
```

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages ={
        "com.test.Connection"
})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Reservation ( Reservation.pom) package

---

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>Connection</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Connection (Connection.pom) package

---

..
..Connection.java

Comment: Does the ReservationConfig file have the @Configuration annotation?